# Chatter Plus License, Custom Objects with Formula referring to Standard Object

Tags: chatter, formula, licenses, userlicense

If I have a custom object that has formulas pulling information from related standard, not custom, objects. Will our chatter plus users be able to see the information, or would they have to be full SF license's to see them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula fields and roll up summary fields are evaluated without regards for field level or object level security. As long as the chatter user can see the record, has object level permission, and field level permission on the formula field, they can see the output of the field and filter on the field.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding you... If they have access to the related object, they'll be able to see the formula data from that related object? If they don't have access they won't be able to see it?

Comment: @JeremyT They should always have access to the formula's value, even without access to the object the formula references.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the object and field permissions on the profiles that apply to those users. In order for this to work, your Chatter users must be assigned the "Chatter Only" (a.k.a. "Chatter Plus") user license. Please see the following for more details on the features that come with the different types of Chatter user licenses: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for your answer, da81, however I don't believe it answers my question. This isn't so much a field permission question. I've refined my original question to hopefully make it a little clearer.

Comment: If they have the read access to the formula field, they will be able to see the value returned by the formula field regardless of their access to the object that the formula is returning the data from.